# dynamodb model friends table

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb

I am looking how to model a friends relationship in dynamodb.

Contacts table:

```
(2-way)
User1 -PK,
User2 -RK

 AND

User2 - PK
User1 - RK
```

Problem with this approach is:

-Double the data.

-No Transactions in dynamoDB, so if one item goes throgough and the other doesn't could cause problems.

-If I want to get all of user1's contact I have to do N reads (e.g 1000 contacts that is 1000 read operation taken u...YIKES! this can add up quick)

Next idea was to create an attribute in the 'User item' which would be a string set and would contain all the users contacts. Issues here are again, since the relationship is mutual, I need to update both user items, and again since there are no transactions so this could cause problems.
There will then be a limit of he number of friends (the item size limit in dynamodb).

Is there a better way than the two ways I showed to store contacts inside of dynamodb?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10206/38680

Comment: @rlartiga I am sory, but I don't see how this applies to my question? Could you please expand?